# Google Cloud AutoML Object Detection export CSV object positions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl

I've labelled objects on images with Google Cloud AutoML label tool. Than I've exported csv file. Here is the output:

```
TRAIN,gs://optik-vcm/optikic/80-2020-03-19T11:58:25.819Z.jpg,kenarcizgi,0.92590326,0.035908595,0.9589712,0.035908595,0.9589712,0.9020675,0.92590326,0.9020675
```

On the beauty, it's like that:

```
TRAIN
gs://optik-vcm/optikic/80-2020-03-19T11:58:25.819Z.jpg
kenarcizgi
0.92590326
0.035908595
0.9589712
0.035908595
0.9589712
0.9020675
0.92590326
0.9020675
```

I know first three columns.

I'll increase the images count by making data augmentation. I'll use OpenCV in Python for that. But I need coordinates of objects on the image.

How can I convert these decimals to pixel coordinations? Or is there any calculation for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called a [NormalizedVertex](https://cloud.google.com/automl/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.models/predict#normalizedvertex).

> A vertex represents a 2D point in the image. The normalized vertex coordinates are between 0 to 1 fractions relative to the original plane (image, video). E.g. if the plane (e.g. whole image) would have size 10 x 20 then a point with normalized coordinates (0.1, 0.3) would be at the position (1, 6) on that plane.

To get a pixel coordinate, you can multiply that number by your input width or length as appropriate.

---

The entire [reference for the CSV formatting](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/csv-format#csv) explains the following (truncated) makes up each row (one row per bounding box or per image):

- `TRAIN` - Which set to assign the content in this row to
- `gs://optik-vcm/...` - Google Cloud Storage URI
- `kenarcizgi` - A label that identifies how the object is categorized
- A bounding box for an object in the image:

  - `x_relative_min`, `y_relative_min`, `x_relative_max`, `y_relative_min`, `x_relative_max`, `y_relative_max`, `x_relative_min`, `y_relative_max`